# How to use jQuery file upload?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to use the [blueimp jQuery File Upload plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload), but without much success. I want my script to upload the file along with other form details when my user clicks the Save button. So far I have this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#custom-file-upload').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        autoUpload: false,
        url: get_current_url() + '/customFileUpload/',
        done: function (e, data) {
            //$.each(data.result, function (index, file) {
            //  $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo(document.body);
            //});
        },
         change: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
                $("#custom-file-upload-filename").text( file.name );
            });
        },
        submit: function(e, data) {
            console.log('submit event fired');
            return false;
        }
    });

    $('.edit-form .btn-submit').click(function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
    })
});
```

So when my user clicks the "Attach File" button, a nice file browser pops up, they pick a file and click Open, and it shows the filename next to the Attach File button.

I do not know how to get it to submit my form now though. I've tried a bunch of different things and after reading the docs I still have no idea.

Comment: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Multiple-File-Input-Fields-in-One-Form

Comment: @RajatSinghal I said in my post I read the docs. I can't get that example to work for me.

Comment: The write up for jquery-file-upload is pretty poor at best. The code examples aren't great either. I've having the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't get this to work either and ended up using the [forms-plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/). The usage is pretty straightforward and there are good examples on the page.

You just code a normal form in HTML and attach the jQuery like this:

```
$('#myForm1').ajaxForm(options);
```